# PNR Status Process

Tags: android

I am android Application Developer.
I am working on Android platform for Mobile Devices.
I want to know the PNR (Train status)
how to access the PNR status Information our Project 
Please help me.

Comment: Where PNR data is? You question is not descriptive.

Comment: PNR Status shows the Train Reservation Confimarion. Kindly look for this link http://www.indianrail.gov.in/pnr_Enq.html

Comment: **That's a government site and illegal leeching will land you in trouble.**

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using XML Parser, go to indianrailway.gov site and search for the PNR status you want, now put this URL in your code & see, it will return you an xml in result. Now you need to parse this XML to get your PNR status.

Comment: what is the method or url used in indianrailway.gov site to get pnr status as xml format? i don't see one in that

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways of achieving this by parsing xml or by parsing JSON data. here is a link by which u can get both xml n JSON out put.
http://www.eyvaiinfotech.in/mobile/api.php?pnrno=[PNR No.]

Comment: Broken link + Can you elaborate, I'm not even sure if this is a real answer. Thanks

Comment: @ForceMagic: the link is not broken, the pnr no. must have been flushed, use a valid pnr no.
the link provides two set of outputs 
1)JSON format and,
2)XML format by default it produces JSON.
and use a JSOn parser to extract the values and display it in your android app.

Comment: Ah I see, well you might want to include this information in your post. Use the edit link button to add more explanation to your answer.